angular-datatables child rows and not displayed correctly
I am using https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables to render the data table in my project.
I am using ajax call to load the paginated contents in to the table, and when I try to show the details child row the row content is not showing correctly.
You can see the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1u2vjh
Note: Also you can see the code that I referred https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vs13py. It is working fine without the ajax call. When I tried to modify the same and added ajax call the code is not working correctly.

Aside, I don't see why you need ajax when you are rendering the row with *ngFor. You should provide the data to dtOptions.
